# How to check before COUNT operation?

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum

1) I have a table named "plan_info_upload" which is like:

```
site_id site_name   2G_bw   3G_bw   route_path
1       MBCGP1      11      0       abc>bcd>cde
2       BOPBG2      12      22      mnl>khl>jhg
3       BOPCB1      11      0       abc>bcd>khl>bbo
4       BOSBB1      0       25      bops>doc>abc>bcd>jkl
```

I have to find how many 2g & 3g bw & total 2g & 3g bw of a unique_hop from the routh_path. but if its 2G_bw or 3G_bw is zero, it do not count it. but I do not understand how to check it if its value is 0 or not before count.

My code is here:

```
<?php
    $unique_hop=$_POST['unique_hop']; 
    $i = 0;
    $sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(2G_bw) AS no_of_2G, SUM(2G_bw) AS total_2G_bw, COUNT(3G_bw) AS no_of_3G, SUM(3G_bw) AS total_3G_bw FROM plan_info_upload WHERE route_path LIKE '%$unique_hop%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $no_of_2G = $row['no_of_2G'];
            $total_2G_bw = $row['total_2G_bw'];
            $no_of_3G = $row['no_of_3G'];
            $total_3G_bw = $row['total_3G_bw'];
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo ++$i;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $unique_hop;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $no_of_2G;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total_2G_bw;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $no_of_3G;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $total_3G_bw;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

from 1st table, if I select unique_hop "abc>bcd" , then 3 routh_path have this string & count & sum their existing 2G_bw & 3G_bw.

My desire output will be:

```
unique_hop     no_of_2G   total_2G_bw   no_of_3G   total_3G_bw
abc>bcd        2          22            1          25
```

But the output is coming like that:

```
unique_hop     no_of_2G   total_2G_bw   no_of_3G   total_3G_bw
abc>bcd        3          22            3          25
```

so how to check before COUNT operation? please anybody help me to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(nullif(2G_bw, 0)) AS no_of_2G, SUM(2G_bw) AS total_2G_bw, COUNT(nullif(3G_bw, 0)) AS no_of_3G, SUM(3G_bw) AS total_3G_bw FROM plan_info_upload WHERE route_path LIKE '%$unique_hop%'";
```